# What is wrong with below proof that E[XY|X] not equal to E[Y|X]

Tags: probability, conditional-expectation, conditional-probability, expected-value

The equality above is wrong. But what was the issue with below derivation? Set $T=XY$
$$
E[YX|X=x]=\int_a^b t f_{T|X=x}(t) dt
$$
perform change of variables, $dt=x dy$. So
$$
E[YX|X=x]=\int_{\frac{a}{x}}^{\frac{b}{x}} yx f_{T|X=x}(yx) x dy.
$$
Now, so 
$$
f_{T|X=x}(yx)=\frac{1}{x}f_{Y|X=x}(y).
$$
Therefore 
$$
E[YX|X=x]=\int_{\frac{a}{x}}^{\frac{b}{x}} yx f_{Y|X=x}(y) dy=x\int_{\frac{a}{x}}^{\frac{b}{x}} y f_{Y|X=x}(y) dy\ne x E[Y|X=x].
$$
Thanks to Sangchul and Henry, some issues were fixed.

---

Using joint density:
\begin{align*}
\int_{R(X)}\int_{R(T)} t \frac{f_{T,X}(t,x)}{f_X(x)}dt dx&=\int_{R(X)}\int_{R(T)/x} xy \frac{f_{XY,X}(xy,x)}{f_X(x)}|x|dy dx
\end{align*}
Similar problem. So it's the integration bounds...

---

Sorry, if range of $XY$ is on $a$ to $b$... range of $Y$ changes with $X$.

Comment: The first equation is wrong.  You should start with a double integral over the joint probability.  The $X$ integral doesn't simplify in this way.

Comment: @Paul conditional distribution is univariate. Where does the joint come from? I need to use something like $E[g(X)E[Y|X]]=E[g(X)Y]$? Is there any way not to use this? Why is the first equation wrong?

Comment: What leads you to believe that $f_{T|X=x}(yx) = f_{Y|X=x}(y)$?

Comment: your third equation looks wrong:I would have thought $f_{T|X=x}(xy)=\frac1x f_{Y|X=x}(y)$ as you stretch the density

Comment: You all are right. That solves the issue. Thanks!